# An exception in a branched chain does not interrupt the entire CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java, completable-future

Behavior of CompletableFuture is such that an exception in a branched chaining will not necessarily interrupt the entire CompletableFuture chain.

Looking for ways to overcome this.

This test represents just a small fragment of the usage. The actual scenario will have such a chain of millions. Another case is when the cause of the failed node is an Out Of Memory situation, which then escalates and worsens the situation, as each thread still tries to continue and eventually also gets OOM.

Java version: 8

The test demonstrates the case:
A = (B + C) * (D / E),
where each variable and operation is represented as a CompletableFuture
[See pictorial representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNxCb.png)

When one part has an exception, it doesn't abort other asynchronous parts, only the root (A) is notified.

where "Root" is "A" (or the result of the multiplication), and the node which fails is "D / E" (e.g. div-by-zero), and nodes B & C on the left branch are still busy with asynchronous activity.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

    static BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> ADD = (a, b) -> a + b;
    static BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> MULTIPLY = (a, b) -> a * b;
    static BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> DIVIDE = (a, b) -> (double) (a.intValue() / b.intValue());

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    // A =  (B + C) * (D / E)
    @Test
    public void cf() {
        CompletableFuture<Double> d = getD();
        CompletableFuture<Double> e = getE();
        CompletableFuture<Double> b = getB();
        CompletableFuture<Double> c = getC();
        CompletableFuture<Double> a = null;
        CompletableFuture<Double> firstArg = null;
        CompletableFuture<Double> secondArg = null;
        try {

            firstArg = b.thenCombineAsync(c, ADD); // B + C
            secondArg = d.thenCombine(e, DIVIDE); // D / E

            a = firstArg.thenCombineAsync(secondArg, MULTIPLY); // (B + C) * (D / E)

            firstArg.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
                System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " Result (B + C): " + r);
            });

            secondArg.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
                if (r != null) {
                    System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " Result (D / E): " + r);
                }
                if (t != null) {
                    System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " Exception occurred while calculating (D / E): "
                            + t.getMessage());
                }
            });

            a.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " Exception occurred while calculating A: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        assertTrue(a.isCompletedExceptionally());
        assertTrue(secondArg.isCompletedExceptionally());
        assertFalse(firstArg.isCompletedExceptionally());
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Double> getB() {
        return get(15, 3000, "B");
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Double> getC() {
        return get(5, 4000, "C");
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Double> getD() {
        return get(100, 1000, "D");
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Double> getE() {
        return get(0, 500, "E");
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Double> get(final double val, final int time, final String name) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " Start: " + name);
                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + " End: " + name);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return val;
        }, executor);
    }

}
```

Result:
Input: B = 15, C = 5, D = 100, E = 0;
Computation of B and C doesn't stop when there is an exception in the other branch (D/E)

```
14:59:08 Start: E
14:59:08 Start: C
14:59:08 Start: B
14:59:08 Start: D
14:59:08 End: E
14:59:09 End: D
14:59:09 Exception occurred while calculating (D / E): java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
14:59:11 End: B
14:59:12 End: C
14:59:12 Result (B + C): 20.0
14:59:12 Exception occurred while calculating A: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: Replace “not necessarily” with “never”. `CompletableFuture` does not support interruption in general. That’s somewhat buried in [the `cancel` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel(boolean)), but derivable from the general way, `CompletableFuture` works. A is not “the root” of anything. It’s a completion stage depending on two others, hence, will fail when either of them fails. `firstArg` does not depend on `secondArg`, hence, is not affected when the `secondArg` stage fails.

Comment: Understood. Do you suggest a way to handle this scenario? I want to abort all stages when an exception happens in one of them.

Comment: I think, `CompletableFuture` is just not the right tool for this. You’d have to somehow remember the stages you need to cancel and then face the fact that a) cancelling a bunch of stages does not happen instantaneously and b) this requires an additional significant amount of memory whereas you said, you are already encountering situations of insufficient memory.